# Ruby `gsub` of escape character

Tags: ruby, regex, escaping, gsub

File `escape.txt` contains `"/\\/"` (slash, backslash, backslash, slash). File `test_gsub.rb` has:

```
content = File.open(ARGV[0]).read
content.gsub! content, content
puts content
```

This code will output `"/\\/"` (slash, backslash, slash), i.e, oneback slash is escaped.

I am wondering if there is a way to disable this escape functionality. I want to output (slash, backslash, backslash, slash).

If I delete `gsub`, it will output (slash, backslash, backslash, slash).

This feature is important because I need to deal with raw text, and `gsub` will always escape these escape characters.

Comment: `File.open(ARGV[0]).read` -> `File.read(ARGV[0])` or maybe even `ARGF.read`.

Answer (score 1):

```
content.gsub! content, content => content
```

In the [docs for `gsub`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.1/String.html#method-i-gsub) you can find this

> If replacement is a String it will be substituted for the matched
>   text. It may contain back-references to the pattern’s capture groups
>   of the form \d, where d is a group number, or \k, where n is a
>   group name. If it is a double-quoted string, both back-references must
>   be preceded by an additional backslash. However, within replacement
>   the special match variables, such as $&, will not refer to the current
>   match.
>
> If the second argument is a Hash, and the matched text is one of its
>   keys, the corresponding value is the replacement string.

Using a hash instead of a string prevents `\` from being treated specially.

Although the docs for `gsub!` don't mention the hash it seems to work fine (perhaps it's an oversight)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11485376)

Comment: @HappyCoder, It's not a critique or a clarification. It succinctly shows how to escape content to get the result asked for. Did you understand the question differently?

Comment: The answer was flagged for low quality! It will be in everybody's interest to just explain what the above line of code is doing.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I think you understand my question correctly. However, this solution seems to produce some new problem. When I put `/  \\/` in escape.txt, it will give me `/\ \ \\/\n`, which even prints slash n. I simply want the original text to be printed, not altered in any way. Do you know how to make this happen?

Comment: @ZEWEICHU, ok I'll work on fixing this answer. While I do that, can you add some more test cases to your question?

Comment: @JohnLaRooy Thanks! A friend just helped me figured this out. I can do content = content.gsub(content){content} and it will work.

Comment: Yeah thanks @JohnLaRooy, I just faced this when doing substitutions for JSON data strings, and this solution helped me when straightforward s.gsub('replace_me', replacement) code gave unexpected results (and broke resulting JSON in my case!) re backslashes escaping: http://screencast.com/t/JserXhc25